# how can I run old programs from a MIPS?

Tags: software-installation, portability, elf, mips, irix

I have an old PC with a program called atomTV, for viewing, and producing movies from molecular trajectory files. I only have a binary, and the platform it ran on was 64-bit MIPS architecture, where I was running IRIX. I have spoke with the creator, and he says he lost the source. My IRIX PC has died recently, but I still want to use this program. What can be done?

The files are xyz, dcd, pdb and that type of thing. Preferably, I would like to know some way to run the program in a modern Unix/Linux environment. I have access to all the old files from the OS if that matters.

When I tried to run the program in Linux, I got wrong ELF type errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best bet is for you to acquire another SGI machine, unfortunately. There are several open source MIPS emulators but their functionality does vary.

Available emulators include:

- [GXemul](http://gxemul.sourceforge.net/)
- [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)

*Update:* Newer releases of [MAME](https://www.mamedev.org/) are now able to run certain releases of IRIX, emulating an Indy. Instructions are available on the [IRIX Network Wiki](https://wiki.irix.cc/emulation).

Comment: Thank Mario and Luigi!

Comment: I guess things have come full circle now - I'm sure many 90s arcade games were designed on SGIs... :)

Comment: They were designed on SGI, and they ran on MIPS. Says Wikipedia: "Historically, video game consoles such as the Nintendo 64, Sony PlayStation, PlayStation 2, and PlayStation Portable used MIPS processors."
  I was using a router until last year which ran MIPS, and there must be millions of printers with MIPS CPUs still in use.